# jQuery dropdown bootstrap not working with some case

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a question about my jQuery Bootstrap Dropdown. I have a problem when I try open the dropdown menu and then try to right click menu, the dropdown will appear disappear. And when I try to scroll down, the dropdown not fit with the root menu.

What I want is :

1. Make keep dropdown show when I try to right click the menu.
2. Make dropdown fit (fixed) when I try to scroll bar, it will stay to fit.

CSS :

```
.dropdown
{
position: absolute;
z-index: 9999999;
display: none;
}
```

for more detail see my fiddle for [demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/TqyjR/)

Anyone please advice. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TqyjR/4/)

change like this.

```
.dropdown
{
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 9999999;
    display: none;
    top: 35px;
    right: 6px;
}
```

and comment

`position()` in show method.

and comment

```
$(window).on('resize', position);
```

Comment: How about when I try to right click ? It still disappear when I try to right click

Comment: on right-click it is not disappearing for me. i see this in chrome.

Comment: @AseanJazz are you seeing my fiddle in other than chrome?

Comment: Hi try this demo : http://jsfiddle.net/TqyjR/9/ the dropdown not fit. try to scroll

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/TqyjR/12/ i did the same changes as i described in my answer and it works.